# If an infinite well-ordered set has initial segments of finite cardinality only, is the set isomorphic to $\mathbb N$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Let $A$ be an infinite well-ordered set. Every initial segment of $A$ is finite. Is $A$ isomorphic to $\mathbb N$?

What's the way to think about it? Should I build an explicit isomorphism? What should I look at?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This is true. And you should build an explicit isomorphism, because there is really just one isomorphism. Let me give you a hint about that.

**HINT:** Every initial segment has a unique cardinality.

Comment: I was trying to solve this as well. So either $A$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb N$, or $A$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb N$'s initial segment, or vice versa. But the last option isn't possible since every initial segment of $A$ is finite. Why can't $A$ be isomorphic to an initial segment of $\mathbb N$?

Comment: The assumption is that $A$ is infinite, but every proper initial segment of $A$ is finite. Use the hint to construction an isomorphism between $A$ and $\Bbb N$. Sure, you can argue by a "two sided embedding" and use the fact that if two well-orders embed into each other as [improper] initial segments then they are isomorphic; but here you can directly construct a bijection which is an order isomorphism.

Comment: I tried it for lots of time. I'm just not sure how to solve this one. I just can't see how the fact that every initial segment is finite is useful here...

Comment: Have you read my hint?

Comment: So you can send maybe every initial segment to its cardinality?

Comment: Almost, but that's the idea. Note that every proper initial segment has an element defining it (namely, the least element not in the initial segment).

Comment: $A$ is a well ordered group, so it has a minimal element $a$. There exists an element coming exactly 'after' it (not sure of the English term) $b$, so $|A_b|=1$. We can keep going and we'll get that the isomorphism is $f(x)=|A_x|$. Does that seem right?

Comment: (1) The term is set, not group; (2) yes that is the general idea.