# Question regarding initial segment and transfinite induction.

Tags: induction, set-theory, order-theory, well-orders, transfinite-induction

Suppose $X$ is an uncountable well-ordered set with $\leq$.For $x\in X$ ,define the initial segment of $X$ determined by $x$ as $I(x)=\{y\in X| y\leq x $ and $y\neq x\}$.Now my question is ,does there exist an $x\in X$ such that $I(x)$ is countably infinite?I think intuitively that it should occur but higher cardinalities are not clear enough for me.Can someone guide me a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are many such $x$: the first is $\min\{y\in X:I(y)\text{ is not finite}\}$. [This question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842474/if-an-infinite-well-ordered-set-has-initial-segments-of-finite-cardinality-only?rq=1) point the way to showing that it is only countably infinite.

Comment: @BrianMScott You are right

Comment: I want to know something.Clearly we can count $1,2,3,........,n,..........$.But can we count like $\aleph_0,\aleph_0+1,............$

Comment: @KishalaySarkar: Yes, though for ordinals the correct notation is $\omega,\omega+1,\omega+2,\ldots$. When you use $\aleph$, you’re talking about cardinals, and for cardinal arithmetic $\aleph_0+n=\aleph_0$ for all finite $n$.

Comment: where can I find more about them?

Comment: @KishalaySarkar: That depends on how much serious set theory you already know and how rigorous a treatment you want. You can get a bare bones description from the Wikipedia articles on [ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) and [ordinal arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic), but for much more than that you’ll probably need a good introduction to formal set theory. The [one by Hrbacek & Jech](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Revised-Expanded-Chapman-Mathematics/dp/0824779150) is good. I’ve not read them carefully, but Bill Weiss has a set of ...

Comment: ... [free notes](https://www.math.toronto.edu/weiss/set_theory.pdf) [PDF] that include what appears to be a decent chapter on ordinals, though you probably have to wade through quite a bit of formalism to get there.

Comment: Can you please help me with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3616669/construction-of-an-uncountable-set-using-well-ordering-principle